# Best way to merge ActiveRecords objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have @posts that belong to user. I am trying to render @posts but also append users name and city to it. I was thinking it would be possible to do something like

```
    respond_to do |format|                                                                                                                                    

        format.json  {                                                                                                                                        
          @post_arr = Array.new                                                                                                                               
          @posts.each do |post|                                                                                                                               
            @post_arr[post.id] = post + post.user.name + post.user.city                                                                                       
          end                                                                                                                                                 
          render json: @post_arr                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                     
     end
```

I get undefined method `+' for #

I also tried creating virtual attributes in post model and assign it as such
post.author = post.user.name
post.author_city = post.user.city
 but it just shows  user_id in json(which is the foreign key)

I try merge as well but that doesn't work. What would be a proper way to do it in rails

EDIT: I got it to work with

```
format.json  {                                                                                                                                        
          @post_arr = Array.new                                                                                                                               
          @posts.each do |post|                                                                                                                               
            @post_arr << post.as_json.merge!({:author_name => post.user.name, :author_city => post.user.city})                                                
          end                                                                                                                                                 
          render json: @post_arr                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                     
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use `jbuilder` gem which is for creating complex json response.

You do below, if you want to use `jbuilder`

Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController    
  def action_name
     responde_to do |format|
       format.json  # => render app/views/posts/action_name.json.jbuilder
     end
  end
end
```

View(`app/views/posts/action_name.json.jbuilder`)

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :name # response post's id and name as same key
  json.user do
    json.name post.user.name  # response post.user.name as name
    json.city post.user.city  # response post.user.city as city
  end
end
```

And response is

```
[
  {"id":1,"name":"post1","user":{"name":"user1","city":"city1"}},
  {"id":2,"name":"post2","user":{"name":"user1","city":"city1"}}
]
```

Comment: can you explain where you got json.user in jbuilder file

Comment: Although it's wrong answer..., jbuilder's basic format is `json.key value`. 
`key` is key of json (ex: id, name, user, ...) and you can decide what you want. `value` is value of json (ex: 1, 2, post1, post2, ..) and you set value ActiveRecord objects's value. Pleas check https://github.com/rails/jbuilder, if you wanna learn more detail about `jbuilder`.